# Copy files whose name is in a list

Tags: python, numpy, directory

I want to copy files to a new directory (good_images) whose name is in the list of names

I have over 60,000 images and a list of 16,000 names. I know for a fact every name in the list matches a name of an image. For example, the images are named 100079.jpg and the list is 100079. I have appended .jpg to the end of every number in the list but that hasn't helped.

```
import os
from shutil import copy2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
Good_File_Names_jpg = []
for i in Good_File_Names:
    Good_File_Names_jpg.append('%s.jpg' % i) #add .jpg to end of list so its similar to file names
for i in (Good_File_Names):
    for j in os.listdir('images_training_rev1_editing'):
        if j.startswith('Good_File_Names[i]'):
            os.chdir('images_training_rev1_editing')
            copy2('%s' % j, 'good_images')
            os.chdir('..')
            print(j)
```

I know the loop works because it takes 10 minutes to run and if I replace 'Good_File_Names[i]' with a number (let's say 100078) it successfully copies 100078.jpg to the new directory.
I think the issue is located in the `j.startwith` line. Probably something to do with how the variable is passed through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have your `j.startswith('Good_File_Names[i]'):` in quotes so Python interprets it as a string. You are also already iterating through the values of `Good_File_Names` with your `i` variable. Replacing the code in question with `j.startswith(i):` should solve the issue.

Comment: That gives an index error
IndexError: index 100078 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 16928

Comment: My bad, try `j.startswith(i):`